# rescale intercept and slope from the metadata for Nifti files

Tags: python-3.x, dicom, itk, nifti

Does ITK/SimpleITK automatically cater for the HU by using rescale intercept and slope from the metadata for Nifti files, as it does for dicom files ([source](https://blog.kitware.com/dicom-rescale-intercept-rescale-slope-and-itk/))?  If it doesn't how can I read the metadata in python 3.4? I went through [this](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1NiftiImageIO.html) class however I can't seem to access the ReadImageInformation() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the source [code](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/75babc2b45ba0f8f2f60d6cdb5e8a0ffcc1e77fa/Modules/IO/NIFTI/src/itkNiftiImageIO.cxx#L736-L812), slope/intercept rescaling is done automatically.

Comment: Thank you! stupid of me not to have seen that! How can I read metadata of nifti in python 3.4 (my continued question)?

Comment: This thread is for GDCMImageIO, but similar should work for NitfiImageIO: https://cmake.org/pipermail/insight-users/2014-June/050549.html

Comment: This C++ example might also be of interest: https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/Examples_2IO_2DicomSeriesReadPrintTags_8cxx-example.html